# Swagger ui shows duplicate model variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, swagger, swagger-ui

Swagger-ui shows duplicate model variables when in edit and none edit mode. This happens to every single model shown on the ui have duplicate model variable. Not sure if this is due to using kotlin but its really frustrating and confusing. The duplicate variable seems to have $timefundcharity after each variable.

Each model is also a MongoDb entity annotated with @Document

Any help is welcome

```
{
  "charityId$charity": 0,
  "createdAt$charity": "2019-06-19T20:16:33.735Z",
  "id": 0,
  "id$charity": 0,
  "userId": 0,
  "userId$charity": 0,
  "charityId": 0,
  "createdAt": "2019-06-19T20:16:33.735Z"
}
```

[image: Image of swagger-ui]
[image: Image of swagger-ui model view]

I have looked around the internet on how to resolve this but it seems no one really has come across this issue and thought i better reach out here.

At first i thought maybe it was the swagger configuration but it doesn't seems to be that either as i have compared the configuration with other sources

```
@Document(collection = "CharityFollowers")
@ApiModel
data class CharityFollower
(
        internal var userId: BigInteger,
        internal var charityId: BigInteger,
        internal var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
){
    @Id internal lateinit var id : BigInteger
}
```

swagger config

```
@Bean
fun productApi(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_12)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.martin.charity.controllers"))
                .build()
                .securityContexts(arrayListOf(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(arrayListOf(this.securitySchema(), this.apiKey(), this.apiCookieKey()))
    }
```

I am expecting the result not to have duplicate model variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after alot of try and error. The reason this was happening was to do with the modifiers, its best to remove any modifiers such as the internal modifier. after removing the modifiers the issues was then fixed